# How to find midpoint on an arc across uneven heights?

Tags: geometry

Input data: `H`, `H1`, `L` and `R`,

where `H` and `H1` — height (left, right), `L` - base and `R` — arch height.

---

I found:

$$R = R - \sqrt{R^2 - L^2/4}$$

$$AD = \sqrt{L^2 + (H-H_1)^2}$$

$$AB = \sqrt{R^2 + (AD/2)^2}$$

But I do not understand how to find `AG` and `AF`, which are the coordinates of the point `B(x, y)`.

[image]

Comment: There seems to be something off about your first formula. $R$ is both on the left hand side and the right hand side of the equation.

Comment: Is $ABD$ an arc of a circle? Because it isn't drawn as such.

Comment: @AlexanderGeldhof -> *Is ABD an arc of a circle?* - yes.

Comment: [Similar or duplicated](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3380672/how-to-find-mid-point-of-a-slant-arc)

Comment: @Ripi2 no, there through the radius, and here through the height.

Comment: There are multiple ways to solve this. Are you allowed to use trigonometry? Or vectors (dot product etc.)? Or is this supposed to be solved purely using euclidean geometry?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/87374/701774 - another solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Let A be the origin and $(u,v)$ be the coordinates of C. They are,

$$u = \frac L2,\>\>\>\>\>v=\frac{H-H_1}{2}$$

Then, the coordinates of B are $(u - R\sin\theta,  v + R\cos\theta)$, or

$$x = \frac L2 - R\sin\theta, \>\>\>\>\> y = \frac{H-H_1}{2} + R\cos\theta\tag{1}$$

where $\cos\theta$ and $\sin\theta$ are obtained vis the right triangle AED,

$$\cos\theta = \frac{L}{\sqrt{L^2+(H-H_1)^2}},\>\>\>\>\>
\sin\theta = \frac{H-H_1}{\sqrt{L^2+(H-H_1)^2}}$$

Substitute above into (1) to obtain the results,

$$x = \frac L2 - \frac{R(H-H_1)}{\sqrt{L^2+(H-H_1)^2}}$$
$$y = \frac{H-H_1}{2} + \frac{RL}{\sqrt{L^2+(H-H_1)^2}}$$

Comment: `Y` incorrect. Need to add `H1`. https://codepen.io/doox911/pen/KKKmwXO.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/87374/701774 - another solution

Answer (score 1):

Assume $A$ is the origin.

1. Calculate the coordinates of the unit vector $\vec{e} = (e_x, e_y)$ in the direction of $\vec{AD}$, using $H, H_1$ and $L$.
2. $\vec{AC} = x \cdot \vec{e}$, with x being $\ldots$ ?
3. Note that $\vec{CB}$ has the direction of $\vec{f}$, with $\vec{f}$ being $\vec{e}$ rotated 90 degrees counterclockwise. The coordinates of $\vec{f}$ will then be $(-e_y, e_x)$.
4. $\vec{CB} = x\cdot \vec{f}$, with $x$ being $\ldots$ ?
5. $\vec{AB} = \vec{AC} + \vec{CB}$.

Comment: I do not understand your decision, please write in more detail.

Comment: Please explain in more detail where you are not following.

Comment: What are `x`,  `f` and can you give an example with calculations?

Answer (score 1):

Since the question is a variation of 
[another one](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3385550/122782),
the only difference is that instead the radius $R$ of the arc,
the distance $|EX|$ is given.

[image]

So, using [the previous answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3385550/122782)
where we have relations

\begin{align} 
|CD|&=\sqrt{L^2+(h_2-h_1)^2}
,\\
|EX|&=R-\tfrac12\,\sqrt{4R^2-|CD|^2}
,
\end{align}

we now can find  $R$ in terms of $|CD|$ and $|EX|$,
namely

\begin{align} 
R&=\tfrac18\,\frac{|CD|^2}{|EX|}
+\tfrac12\,|EX|
\end{align}

and continue with the solution as before with known $R$.